# Mongoid field hash as Struct

Tags: ruby, serialization, deserialization, ruby-on-rails-5, mongoid6

Is it possible to configure a mongoid `field` to deserialize as a `Struct` rather than a `Hash` ? ([with defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15055852/2832282))

My use case : a company with a subscription plan stored as a hash in my model.

Previously as a hash

```
class Company
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :subscription, type: Hash, default: {
      ends_at: 0,
      quantity: 0,
      started_at: 0,
      cancelled: false,
    }
```

I wish I didn't have to write `Company.first.subscription[:ends_at]`, I'd rather write `Company.subscription.ends_at`

I figured something like the following would work better

```
class Company
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :subscription_plan, type: Struct, default: Struct.new(
    :ends_at, :quantity, :started_at, :cancelled
  ) do
    def initialize(
      ends_at: nil, 
      quantity: 0,
      starts_at: nil,
      cancelled: false
    ); super end
  end
end
```

It would be even better if the plan could be defined in a class

```
class SubscriptionPlan < Struct.new(
  ends_at, :quantity, :starts_at, :cancelled
) do
  def initialize(
  ends_at: nil, 
  quantity: 0,
  starts_at: nil,
  cancelled: false
); super; end
end

class Company
  field :subscription_plan, type: SubscriptionPlan, default: SubscriptionPlan.new
end
```

How can I make it work ?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Take this with a grain of salt, as I've never used either MongoDB or Mongoid.
Still, googling for "custom type" brought me to this [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/6.0.0/mongoid-documents/#fields).

Here's an adapted version of the custom type example :

```
class SubscriptionPlan

  attr_reader :ends_at, :quantity, :started_at, :cancelled

  def initialize(ends_at = 0, quantity = 0, started_at = 0, cancelled = false)
    @ends_at = ends_at
    @quantity = quantity
    @started_at = started_at
    @cancelled = cancelled
  end

  # Converts an object of this instance into a database friendly value.
  def mongoize
    [ends_at, quantity, started_at, cancelled]
  end

  class << self

    # Get the object as it was stored in the database, and instantiate
    # this custom class from it.
    def demongoize(array)
      SubscriptionPlan.new(*array)
    end

    # Takes any possible object and converts it to how it would be
    # stored in the database.
    def mongoize(object)
      case object
      when SubscriptionPlan then object.mongoize
      when Hash then SubscriptionPlan.new(object.values_at(:ends_at, :quantity, :started_at, :cancelled)).mongoize
      else object
      end
    end

    # Converts the object that was supplied to a criteria and converts it
    # into a database friendly form.
    def evolve(object)
      case object
      when SubscriptionPlan then object.mongoize
      else object
      end
    end
  end
end

class Company
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :subscription, type: SubscriptionPlan, default: SubscriptionPlan.new
end
```

This should bring you closer to what you wanted to do.

Note that the default `SubscriptionPlan` will be shared by every company with a default. It might lead to some weird bugs if you modify the default plan in one company.

Comment: Hi, I will try that, but be careful you gave the link to a very outdated Mongoid documentation (I think version 2 or something). I'm working with mongoid edge (mongoid 6 / MongoDB 3.x). There's even `old` in the URL

Comment: You're right. I didn't check, I just used the first link I found on Google.

Comment: I was lucky, the documentation doesn't seem to have changed since old mongoid.

Comment: Hey, I seem to be having progress with your code. But during some serialization/deserialization process I'm getting `NoMethodError: undefined method `bson_type' `. I'm not sure what this method is.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was just reimplementing a nested document without the ID. In the end I decided to switch to a normal embedded document for my `subscription`, since having an extra ID field isn't a problem and I get mongoid scopes as bonus. I can always add `Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic` in case I want to support any key.

Nevertheless the question and other answer remains relevant for one who wants to create his own types.